# how to pass information to your socket

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io, axios

I made a simple login that works and have a small database connected to my server. Whenever a user logs in correctly, a web socket connection will be initiated. However, when I establish a socket connection between the client once they are authenticated, I want to add information to the socket I just opened in order to keep track of the name of all the users that have a connection with my server. I've tried many different ways and eventually gave up. Here is my client code:

```
function authenticate()
{
   axios.post('/login', {
      Username: document.getElementById("username").value,
      Password: document.getElementById("password").value
   })
   .then(function (response) {
      let socket=io();
      /*console.log(response.data[0].ClientFirstName + 
      response.data[0].ClientLastName);*/
      socket.on('connect', function(){ <-this event doesn't fire
         console.log("connect"); <-is not displayed in the browser's console
      })
      window.location.replace('/public/Main.html');
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
   });
}
```

And here is my server code:

```
const Express=require('express');
const path=require('path');
var app = Express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "ChatDB"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err)throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});

app.use(Express.json())
app.use('/public', Express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  let a=req.body.Username;
  let b=req.body.Password;
  let query="SELECT ClientID, ClientFirstName, ClientLastName FROM Client WHERE ClientUsername=\'" + a + "\' AND ClientPassword=\'" + b + "\';";
  con.query(query, function (err, rows) {
    if (err){
      throw err;
    }
    else if(rows.length)
    {
      console.log(rows);
      res.json(rows);
    }
  })
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
})

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000')
});
```

I tried using this in the client to try and get data across but it didn't work or at least I didn't know how to use it on the server side:

```
let socket=io.connect("localhost:3000", {firstname: "adsfasdf", lastname: 
"asdfsadf"});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only so far we can take you here, without just doing this for you. Did you check out the really helpful [tutorial on the Socket.io website?](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

The key is realizing that on both your client and your server you are communicating back and forth. You `emit` or `broadcast` messages on one end, and you listen `on` the other.

So in your client, you are initiaziling your socket only after the user has logged in, and then only within the `.then()` of your `axios` call. You probably want to initialize your socket elsewhere, then you can add listeners and send messages anywhere you choose.

Here is a basic example:

**CLIENT**:

```
//initialize socket
const socket = io();

//add all your listeners outside of functions and call other functions in response
io.on('user added', function(user) { console.log({newUser: user}) })

function authenticate() { 
    axios(...).then(response=>{
        let userName = //some data you got back from response

        //send a message to the server who will broadcast
        socket.emit('new user', userName);
    })
}
```

**SERVER**

```
// think of how you want to handle persistence
const users = [];
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    // the server listeners for client initiated messages and responds
    socket.on('new user', function(user) {

        users.push(user);

        //tell everyone a new user joined
        io.emit('user added', user);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
})
```